# Google App Engine users.get_current_user() always returns None

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am trying the examples in the [Google App Engine Getting Started](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstarted/) guide.  I am only using the SDK emulator locally—I have not uploaded to Google yet.

Things are generally working, except for the `users` service.

The example in [Using the Users Service](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstarted/usingusers.html) begins by displaying the fake login screen as expected.  However, the program never proceeds beyond this point because `users.get_current_user()` always returns `None`, no matter which buttons I push on the fake login screen.

My system:

- Fedora 14 Linux
- Python 2.5.6 compiled with openssl-devel and sqlite-devel present

Here is what `dev_appserver.py helloworld/` writes to stdout when I press the "Login" button:

```
INFO     2011-09-19 05:59:53,643 dev_appserver.py:4247] "GET /_ah/login?email=test%40example.com&action=Login&continue=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2F HTTP/1.1" 302 -
INFO     2011-09-19 05:59:53,675 dev_appserver.py:4247] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 -
INFO     2011-09-19 05:59:53,703 dev_appserver.py:4247] "GET /_ah/login?continue=http%3A//localhost%3A8080/ HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Comment: Can you paste your root (/) request handler class as well?.

Comment: Do you have cookies turned off in your browser?

Comment: Please include your code. We can't figure out what's wrong with it without seeing it.